# save-buffers-kill-terminal suddenly does nothing

Tags: exit

suddenly the function `save-buffers-kill-terminal` and `save-buffers-kill-emacs` doesn't kill emacs process without any errors. I have to use `kill-emacs` function to do so.

running emacs -Q and then `save-buffers-kill-terminal` does the intended thing.

**emacs version: GNU Emacs 28.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2022-01-01**

Comment: after checking the configuration, I think the problem is `persp-mode` as unloading it solves the problem, specifically when I have`(setq persp-auto-save-fname nil)` but dont know why.

Comment: "emacs version: GNU Emacs 28.0.50" is crazy.  Not only was there a stable 28.1 release, but it's been out for so long that there has subsequently been a stable 28.2 point release as well.  Meanwhile you're running some arbitrary pre-release build of 28, and so any problems you encounter might only exist in your build.